# How to create a shell script binary without harcoding a string in the nix file

Tags: nix

To create a binary shell script I'm using `writeShellScriptBin`. This function takes a string that represents the shell script to be produced, e.g.:

```hs
  my-script = writeShellScriptBin "my-script" ''
    # Some script
  ''
```

Using `writeShellScriptBin` works great for small scripts, but once the script starts growing the string that produces it becomes hard to maintain. So I was wondering what are the alternatives to `writeShellScriptBin`.

Answer (score -1):

There is [substituteAll](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/a134826450ba8eb8831f221d8ffa21518987eb8e/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix#L497). Example:

```
substituteAll {                                                                 
  src = ./foo.in;                                                 
  name = "foo";                                                     
  dir = "/bin";  # If you omit it, you will get substitution result in $out                                                                 
                                                                                
  isExecutable = true;  # it is script, so you are likely want this.                                                                                                           
  inherit curl jq execline;                                                     
}
```